# Replace upload file Laravel 4

Tags: php, file-upload, replace, laravel

I'm trying to upload files with Laravel 4 and store them with the method `move()` but I want to replace images with the same name without deleting previously the stored image. I've looked at many related questions but I can't find the way I want to, many suggest to delete the image before adding the new image with the same name. I just want to know if there is a method that can allow store images with replacement without deleting.

I'm trying this:

```
if(Input::hasFile('photo'))
{
  $name = str_replace(array('/', '.'), '_', Hash::make(Input::get('login').Input::get('code'))).'.'.Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
  Input::file('photo')->move('images', $name);
}
```

but that works fine with images with new name.

If I delete the image before store it, it works fine for any case:

```
if(Input::hasFile('photo'))
{
  File::delete('images/'.$name);
  $name = str_replace(array('/', '.'), '_', Hash::make(Input::get('login').Input::get('code'))).'.'.Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
  Input::file('photo')->move('images', $name);
}
```

I just want to know if exists a way to do that without using `File::delete()`.

Comment: Suggestion: Why don't you add the code you've got so far showing that with delete so it's more clear which part you'd like to have in a different fashion. I'm not so sure even if it's not actually the same.

Comment: I don't understand what is the goal. Do you want to keep the old image or you want to delete it? If you want to delete it, why not using the delete method?

Comment: I just want to upload an image with a name (e.g. photo.jpg) if that name is taken, I want the old image be replaced by the new one. I thought the method `move()` does that. The solution I found was delete the old image and save the new one with the same name. I just want to know if exists a method to do that without deleting.